# SAS data storage - /*file_location*/ notation

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS and am trying to understand how a specific SAS program is reading data from files:

At this point I understand that libnames tell SAS where to store and retrieve data, but I've also come across this notation at the top of the file I am studying:

```
%read_configuration_file(dataIn = /*rpe_para.*/configuration_file);
```

`read_configuration_file` is a macro my program runs. What I'm really confused about is the `dataIn` file location. Can somebody explain the notation to me?

Comment: Think of the macro as a function - except it doesn't return anything - and then the dataIN is the parameter, and configuration_file is the value.  The /* */ part comments out the library part of the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/* anything */ is a comment in SAS.  The DATAIN parameter has the LIBNAME part commented-out.

Comment: So if I removed the comments, `rpe_para.configuration_file` would allow me to access a library that is different from the one I am currently working in? And if I left the comments in `/*rpe_para.*/ configuration_file` would look for the `configuration_file` in my current working library?